# Is any technical problem with use own html tags in Modern browsers

Tags: html, dom, internet-explorer, syntax, tailwind-css

Sometimes my code gets horribly ugly

Especially when I use frameworks like tailwind
When the project gets big, I can say without exaggeration that 90% of my time is spent finding the desired class between elements

One of the solutions to keep the code clean is to use own tags
I don't mean the new html5 tags like `aside`, `header` , `footer` , `section` , ...

for example

```
<div class="flex items-center justify-center p-4 rounded shadow">
   <div id="inner"> <!--  A dirty tag to prevent display flex from affecting child tags -->
      <div> somedata </div>
      <div> somedata </div>
      <div> somedata </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

can replaced with

```
<card class="flex items-center justify-center p-4 rounded shadow">
   <inner> 
      <div> somedata </div>
      <div> somedata </div>
      <div> somedata </div>
   </inner>
</card>
```

even in vanilla css own tag's make the code more deciplined
example

```
<div class="post">
 <header>
  <div class="header__image">
   <img src="example.jpg">
  <div>
  <div class="header_details">
    ...
  </div>
 </header>
 <div class="post__content">
 </div>
 .....
</div>
```

it can be like

```
<post>
 <header>
    <picture>
       <img src="example.jpg">
    </picure>
 </header>
 <content>
 <p> something </p>
 <content>
 ...
</post>
```

Is there any **Serious technical problems** other than not being supported by old browsers?

Comment: I never use them, but it is perfectly legit to use `<custom-tags>` in your HTML. This is what [MDN: Using custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) has to say about the subject. And here's a nice read explaining some do's and don'ts by [Mathew Taylor: Custom HTML Tags](https://matthewjamestaylor.com/custom-tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 21 day's coding own custom tags my answer is **NO**
I use my own tags like this

default tags:

```
<div class="card">
  <header>
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  </header>
<div class="container">
    <div>John Doe</div>
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

own-tags

```
<card>
<header>
  <image src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
</header>
<container>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <job>Architect & Engineer</job>
  </container>
</card>
```

every thing is fine.

notes :

- `<custome-tags>` default display is `inline`
- `<image>` is synonym for `<img>`
- `<title>` is `text-only` and `display:none` element. you can use `<subject>` instead
- `<col>` is  specifies column properties for each column within a `<colgroup>` element. you can use `<column>` instead